# Setting user name in Google Groups strictly through an elist (not suite) does not work anymore and it needs to?

Tags: google-groups

Up to six month ago putting a person's name then  and directly adding them to a group for an elist worked. Now it doesn't. And I really need to know their names - not just a reiteration of their email address. Please help.